# What do I need to do to display an image on my web page using the ItemService API?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I've uploaded a few images of kittens, teddy bears, flowers, and other cute things to a folder within the Sitecore Media Library. I now need to access them using the ItemService API and display them in my ASP.NET page.

When I access these images by their ItemID, I get 200 (OK) responses, which JSON string containing all the data pertaining to these images. But I'm unable to figure out a way how to display these images within my page. Some of the code snippets I am trying out are the following:

To access the ItemService API:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "image/jpeg");
// I am able to get an HTTP 200 response with the proper JSON with the following line
client.DownloadFile((@"https://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/item/<my item guid>", @"cutePicture.json");
```

I even try the `DownloadData` method of the `WebClient` class and attempt to convert the returned byte array to and Image using multiple ways, but each time I get errors saying 'Invalid Parameter' and others.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "image/jpeg");
var bytes = client.DownloadData(@"https://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/item/<my item guid>");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
     Image myImage = Image.FromStream(ms); // Fails here
     myImage.Save(@"MyCuteImage.jpg");
}
```

I replace the `using` block with the following snippet, but that too doesn't let me convert the byte array to an image.

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
Image myImage = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(bytes); // throws an error saying the parameter is invalid
myImage.Save(@"MyCuteImage.jpg");
```

Could someone please help me out here? Are there any settings/decorations I need to give my page to make Sitecore know that my page is accessing data from it? And how do I achieve my desired result, i.e., displaying a picture got from the Sitecore media library using the ItemService API onto my page? What am I missing here?

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated!

Joonu

Comment: As you are using OData Item Service, take a look in this article -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_odata_item_service . You haven't specified version of Sitecore. Is Image__Url in returned json? Maybe use that parameter. Search for it in that article. That should help you out accessing images... If it's working I will convert this comment to answer with further clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request a media item using ItemService API, You should receive the following field in the JSON respons:

```
ItemMedialUrl: "https://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/-/media/kittens.ashx"
```

You should be able to use that URL to show the image on your ASP.NET web page.